# Django1.5 forloop.counter not incrementing in template

Tags: html, for-loop, django-templates, counter

i cannot seem to get Djangos "forloop.counter" to increment. I have tried to follow tutorials on web to no avail.

First i populate the template with as many rows as exists in **result_get_list**. I then may change few values and submit using POST. Now each row in the outputted table is its own item with values. My controller needs to be able to distinguish each row. For this I would like to append an id. This is the "***_1***" that you see below (second code block). But instead of appending "***_1***" for first row, "***_2***" for second row, *forloop.counter* is not working as i intended and every row has "***_1***" appended.

my code on template is as follows:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

    <div id="div_element">
    <table style=" float: left;" width="445">
    <tr>
        <th width="110"><center>Name</center></th>
        <th width="110"><center>Version</center></th>
        <th width="110"><center>Timestamp</center></th>
        <th width="110"><center>Action</center></th>
    </tr>
    {% if result_get_list %}
        {% for result_row in result_get_list %}
            {% for result_item in result_row %}
            <tr>
                <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="name_{{ forloop.counter }}" value={{result_item.name}}></center></td>
                <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="version_{{ forloop.counter }}" value={{result_item.version}}></center></td>
                <td width="110"><center><input type="text" name="date_{{ forloop.counter }}" value={{result_item.date}}></center></td>
                <td width="110"><center><select name="selected_post_action_{{ forloop.counter }}"><option>none</option><option>delete</option><option>update</option></select></center></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </table>
    </div>

    <div id="div_nextline_section">
        <input type='submit' value='Update!'/>
    </div>

</form>
```

my template outputs as follows *(viewing the html source)*:

```
<tr>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="Name_1" value=ABCDEF></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="Version_1" value=1></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" name="theDate_1" value=0></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><select name="selected_post_action_1"><option>none</option><option>delete</option><option>expire</option><option>update</option></select></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="Name_1" value=DEFGHI></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="Version_1" value=1></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" name="theDate_1" value=0></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><select name="selected_post_action_1"><option>none</option><option>delete</option><option>expire</option><option>update</option></select></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="Name_1" value=GHIJKL></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="Version_1" value=1></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><input type="text" name="theDate_1" value=0></center></td>
    <td width="110"><center><select name="selected_post_action_1"><option>none</option><option>delete</option><option>expire</option><option>update</option></select></center></td>
</tr>
```

Using fiddler and capturing output this is the current result that gets POSTed to the controller *(note the "_1")*:

```
name_1=ABCDEF&ersion_1=1&date_1=0&selected_post_action_1=delete&
name_1=DEFGHI&version_1=1&date_1=0&selected_post_action_1=expire&
name_1=GHIJKL&version_1=1&date_1=0&selected_post_action_1=update
```

My desired output is *(note each row is incremented)*:

```
name_1=ABCDEF&ersion_1=1&date_1=0&selected_post_action_1=delete&
name_2=DEFGHI&version_2=1&date_2=0&selected_post_action_2=expire&
name_3=GHIJKL&version_3=1&date_3=0&selected_post_action_3=update
```

help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I should add this is Django 1.5 using python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. I have a nested forloop. There is another parameter for referencing the parent forloop: **{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}**

```
{% for result_row in result_get_list %}
    {% for result_item in result_row %}
    <tr>
        <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="name_{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" value={{result_item.name}}></center></td>
        <td width="110"><center><input type="text" readonly name="version_{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" value={{result_item.version}}></center></td>
        <td width="110"><center><input type="text" name="date_{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" value={{result_item.date}}></center></td>
        <td width="110"><center><select name="selected_post_action_{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}"><option>none</option><option>delete</option><option>update</option></select></center></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```